# How to remove item from multidimensional object by value

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array

I need to remove item from multidimensional javascript object by value. For example, I have this objecť tree (screenshot contains only part): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13057084/files-tree.png

[image]

I need to remove item by value of "file", so for example from tree on screenshot I need to remove file "9RuOxSPnTR-i_1.jpg".

I tried to use this:

```
$.each(files, function (index_folder,folder) { // foreach files as folders
  $.each(folder, function (index_file,file_data) { // foreach folders as files (index_file = numeric index key of file)    
    delete files[index_folder][index_file];
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm missing a `if (file_data.file == "9Ru…")`, or do you want to delete everything?

Comment: I want to delete only one file, so you are right that I am missing this condition...

Answer (score 2):

Use splice:

```
files[index_folder].splice(index_file, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You use [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) to remove properties from objects and [`.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove elements from arrays:

```
> var o = {a: 1, b: 2};
> delete o.a;
true
> o;
{b: 2}

> var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
> a.splice(2, 1);
['c']
> a;
['a', 'b', 'd']
```